# resize div on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
<style>
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 963px;
    height: 642px;
}
#preload {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.loading {
    position:absolute;
    top: 43%;
    left: 47%;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <img id="preload" src="preload.png"/>
        <img class="loading" src="../effects/loading icon/loading3.gif" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../player/player.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pic1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            var maxWidth = $(window).width();
            var maxHeight = $(window).height();
            var ratio = $("#main").height() / $("#main").width();

            if(maxWidth * ratio > maxHeight) {
                $("#main").height(maxHeight);
                $("#main").width(maxHeight / ratio);
            } else {
                $("#main").width(maxWidth);
                $("#main").height(maxWidth * ratio);
            }
            $("#preload").width($("#main").width());
            $("#preload").height($("#main").height());
        }).trigger('resize');
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is the div and the img inside to auto resize with window resize. The problem is, on 1st time page load, there is a blank space below the div like Picture 1, and when I resize window the space disappear like you can see on Picture 2. Why there is space in Picture 1 and how can I fix it, tks so much :)
[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Update Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7bNjf/

Comment: You should trim your code to only show the code that matters.

Comment: On DOM ready the images are still loading :) Put your logic into a function, and reuse that function inside window .resize and .load

Comment: @RyanJMcGowan there's not much else in the code. What do you suggest for removal?

Comment: Everything that doesn't matter. All the html, css, and javascript that isn't related to the problem you're having just makes finding the code that matters that much harder.

Comment: Rather, put the code and css on f.ex. fiddler and reference that in your post together with only the relevant parts (trigger etc.)

Comment: @RyanJMcGowan how much irrelevant code do _you_ see? I see a long block of CSS, but it seems all relevant

Comment: I updated jsFiddle link, can some1 have a look and help me out :)

Comment: @JanDvorak Meta tags, doctype, script file links, etc. I'd say a third of the lines aren't needed. This question isn't complicated so it's not a very big problem here, but it's not a good habit to get into just posting your entire code file, I'm sure you'd agree.

Comment: @RyanJMcGowan that depends on whether you want a code _sample_ or a [_simple **self-contained** correct example_](http://sscce.org). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22762/194047. The fact that HTML has a lot of boilerplate is unfortunate, but I think we should play along nevertheless.

Comment: @RyanJMcGowan tks for your advise, I will remember that on next question. Btw, can you help me with my question, I still cant fix it. Tks so much :)

Comment: @DucAnh please see my response to Ryan's comment.

Comment: @RyanJMcGowan for one, it avoids questions like "are you sure you included jQuery correctly?" "Did you forget to wrap in `$(document).ready`?" "Are the elements added dynamically?". All of them are valid questions if you don't provide a _complete_ example. Sure, there's a line or two that can be removed (the link to an external CSS (maybe) and the content type (again, I'm not sure), and two of the three external JSes. Still, I think it's  close to minimal.

Answer (score 5):

Refactor the code so that the image.onload calls the resize function initially.

```
<img id="preload" src="preload.png" onload="resizeImage()" />
```

In the script section:

```
function resizeImage() {
    //calculations here...
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeImage, false);
```

(using vanilla JS for illustration where the key-parts you need to change are.. modify as needed).

This implies of course (?) that `resizeImage()` is also called in the onload/onready event for the window.

Comment: inline JS is old stuff and hardly maintainable.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That depends entirely on the project. I do say it's for simplicity (maybe I should change that to 'illustration') to give OP an idea where he needs to fix.

Comment: The lesson is that it needs to be on the onload event as well, so you need to create the resizeImage function and call it onload, AND on resize.

Comment: @RyanJMcGowan It was implied that the call to resize was performed on onload as well. I guess I should be more clear about it. Will modify.

Comment: It made sense to me. I think he saw the inline call to the function and didn't take the time to see how this works as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an answer so I'll put it here:

On DOM ready the images are still loading :) Put your logic into a function, and reuse that function inside window .resize and .load:

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {


     function resizzler(){
        var $main = $('#main');
        var maxWidth = $(window).width();
        var maxHeight = $(window).height();
        var ratio = $main.height() / $main.width();

        if(maxWidth * ratio > maxHeight) {
            $main.height(maxHeight).width(maxHeight / ratio);
        } else {
            $main.width(maxWidth).height(maxWidth * ratio);
        }
        $("#preload").width($main.width()).height($main.height());
    }

    $(window).on('resize load', resizzler );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're resizing the image you're preserving the aspect ratio. If the calculated image height is less that the window height, the image will be "docked" against the top left corner of it's enclosing div given the styling you used (position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0)

The only way you can get it to always fill it's enclosing div is to either clip it or to stretch it and lose it's aspect ratio.

Another alternative is to center the image vertically.

Comment: I dont really understand your answer, can you give me some code  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your image is inside a div name `#main` and in CSS you specify the height width of the #main div.

So I think your image have smaller height than the `#main` div height. After the resize the window you change the height of the `#main` div using jQuery. I think the same height of image and `#main` div solves your problem at first time load

Answer (score 0):

you bind only on "resize" try bind with "load"

```
$(window).on('load resize', function()....
```